# how to configure on Apache proxy (SSL conection) to Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat

I am new in Apache's world, and I need to connect a server (Ubuntu system ) located in my DMZ area to a Tomcat server (Windows server System) in my network. So I wrote on my Ubuntu Apache /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl:

`<VirtualHost *:443>`
     
`<Location /example>`

```
      ProxyPass  http://tomcatIP:8080/example/
      ProxyPassReverse https://mydomain/example/
```

`</Location>`

`</VirtualHost>`

I restart my Apache and on the browser doesnt display anything, however if i choose source code I can see all the php, javascript, html code.
I checked the log from Apache and there are a lot logs like this:

`AH00128: File does not exits: /var/html/...`

I checked my firewall and everything is correct. I don`t know why my apache doesn't search on Tomcat server. Do I need more code? on apache.conf?

Many thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure AJP Connector on Web-Server and on Tomcat Application Server.
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.0-doc/config/ajp.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I will check it. Regarts and happy new year!

Comment: Thank you. I wish you well. Did the configuration work?

Answer (score 0):

Afer read documentation, I checked the Tomcat configuration and I watched that it wasn't the "tipical" Tomcat, it completly customized for Servicedesk software, and after many tries and fails I couldn't do anything, finally the costumer service told me that is impossible an Apache connection. ¬¬
Thanks anyway!!